# how to update woo-commerce variation attribute using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to build a variable subscription with **one time purchase** and **subscription purchase**.

**What i did yet is**

1. Created a lifetime purchase radio button => **(act as onetime purchase)**
2. Woo-commerce variation select input => **(act as subscription purchase)**
3. create a JavaScript function which calls when radio button is clicked

**JavaScript Function**

It select a lifetime option from select attribute but this not trigger actual cart update, as when i click purchase option it says please select a variation first.

```
function manage_billing_type(type){
     if(type==false){                                                   
         $('#method').val( 'One Time' ).changed();                          
     }else{                         
        $('#method').val( 'Monthly' ).changed();                            
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this functionality by variation_id.

What i did is pass respected attribute variation id to JS function and under that function just update variation input id to that attribute variation id.

`<input onchange="manage_billing_type(<?php echo $variations_id[0]; ?>);" type="radio" name="billingmethod">`

```
function manage_billing_type(var_id){  
  $('input.variation_id').val(type).trigger('change');                  
}
```

Now after calling this function, it solves the issue of add product in cart.